# Subsets and Perpendicular Subsets of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of $V$

We want to show that,
$S_1\subseteq S_2 \Rightarrow  S_2^\perp\subseteq S_1^\perp$

Hence, we choose any arbitrary $v \in S_2^\perp$

$\therefore \forall u \in S_2, \left<u,v \right> = 0$

But I do not know how to carry on from here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are off to a good start. We have chosen an arbitrary $v \in S_2^\perp$ we want to show that $v \in S_1^\perp$. Note that $v \in S_1^\perp$ if and only if $\forall u \in S_1$,  $\langle v,u \rangle = 0$.

So let $u \in S_1$, as $S_1 \subseteq S_2$, we have that $u \in S_2$, thus $\langle v,u \rangle = 0$. This is because $v \in S_2^\perp$.

Thus $v \in S_1^\perp$.

Thus $S_2^\perp \subseteq S_1^\perp$.